# Confused on Expected Value

Tags: probability, standard-deviation

I have this question in which I have solved so many times but unsure of the answer i have. could anyone help out?

> ** A cpu manufacturer has a machine which produces microchips. The
>   probability that the machine produces a faulted microchip is given by
>   p = 1/10000. The manufactorer produces n = 6000 chips using the
>   machine. Calculate the probabilty that there are 5 faulted chips, 6
>   faulted chips, 20 faulted chips out of the n = 6000. Moreover, derive
>   the expected number of faulted chips, and the square of the standard
>   deviation.**

My solution gave me 461/10000 as the expected value. Is that correct?

Regards

Comment: The expected number is $6000/10000$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The number $X$ of faulty chips in a sample of $6000$ has *Binomial Distribution*, parameters $p=\frac{1}{10000}$, $n=6000$.

The mean of $X$ is $np$, and the variance (square of the standard deviation) is $np(1-p)$.

So to answer your specific question, the mean of $X$ is $(6000)(1/10000)$.

The probability that there are exactly $k$ faulty chips in the sample is 
$$\binom{6000}{k}p^k (1-p)^{6000-k}.$$
You can use this formula to compute the various probabilities asked for.

**However,** it is possible that you are expected to use the **Poisson** approximation to the Binomial. If the word Poisson is not familiar to you, you can stop reading. If it is familiar, continue.

In this sort of situation, where $p$ is small, $n$ is large, and $np$ "moderate," we can approximate the distribution of $X$ using a Poisson random variable with parameter $\lambda=np=0.6$.

The probability that $X=k$ is well approximated by $e^{-\lambda} \dfrac{\lambda^k}{k!}$.

Answer (score 3):

Give the chips an index and let $X_{i}$ take value $1$ if chip $i$
is faulted and $0$ otherwise.

Then $$X=X_{1}+\cdots+X_{6000}$$ stands for the total number of faulted
chips.

We find: $$\mathbb{E}X=\mathbb{E}X_{1}+\cdots+\mathbb{E}X_{6000}=\frac{1}{10000}+\cdots+\frac{1}{10000}=\frac{6000}{10000}$$

Comment: A very good idea to show the conceptual basis that underlies the "formula."